# How to make a scatter matrix of two vectors

Tags: matrices, vectors, matlab

Assume that you having two vectors $x \in \Re^n$ and $y \in \Re^n$ and you want to create matrix $X \in \Re^{n x n}$.

The element of the matrix can be accessed from $X(i, j) = x_{x,j}$ coordinates, so that means $i$ and $j$ are non-negative integers only $i, j >= 0$

The matrix is going to be a scatter matrix, that means if I plot $x$ and $y$ it might looks like this

[image]

**Problems:**

The problems are that $x$ and $y$ contains decimal numbers of arbitary types e.g `-0.35` or `5.15`. It's difficult to turn them into real integers without change the precision.

So, how can that be done? Turning $x$ and $y$ into a scatter matrix $X$ that every coordinate $x_{i,j}$ has the 8-bit value `255` and the rest of the matrix is only `0`?

**Data:**

Assume that you have this Matlab code

```
x = [linspace(0, 5, 10) linspace(-5, -2, 16)];
y = [5*x(1:13), -7*x(14:26)];
```

And from that you want to create a matrix, as it was plotted with

```
plot(x, y, '.')
```

Notice that this is not a programming question, it's a real math question how to turn $x$ and $y$ inte coordinates where the coordinates cannot be negative.

**My suggestion:**

Firstly. What I think that need to be done is to shift the data so there are only positive values in $x$ and $y$

$$x^* = x - min(x)$$
$$y^* = y - min(y)$$

Then plot it

[image]

Now, the next problem that I need help with, scale $x$ and $y$ so they can be intepreted as integers. How can I achieve that?